# Repository Pattern: Method signature for Edit/Delete methods

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

I'm trying to teach myself the repository pattern, and I have a best practices question.

Imagine I have the entity (this is a linq to sql entity but I've stripped all the linq to sql code and the data annotations attributes for clarity):

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
}
```

The abstract repo for my interface so far is:

```
public interface IPersonRepository
{
    IQueryable<Person> Person { get; }
    void Add(Person person);
    void SubmitChanges();
    // I want an Edit method here
    // I want a Delete method here
}
```

My question is this: What would be the method signature for the edit / delete methods? What would be the best practices for these? If Id for example was the only "uneditable" (i.e. the key) property of a Person, how would you implement this?

Should Edit take a Person parameter, and then the edit method code lookup the entity with the supplied id and edit that way?

Should delete take a Person parameter, or simply an id?

I'm trying to think what would be the most logical, clear way to do it, but I'm getting all confused so thought I'd ask!

Thanks!

Comment: That `SubmitChanges` method needs to go.  That's a Unit-Of-Work concern, not a Repository concern.  Sounds like you're implementing this with a `DataContext` and allowing it to leak through your abstraction.

Comment: Yea I'm using DataContext, what should I be using instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I generaly have them both (entity and Id) for delete:

```
void Delete(Person person);
void DeleteById(int personId);
```

and one with on the entity for save:

```
void Save(Person person);
```

You might also consider to make a generic base repository for the standard CRUD actions:

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T>
{
    T GetById(Guid id);
    IList<T> GetAll();
    void Delete(T entity);
    void DeleteById(Guid id);
    void Save(T entity);
}
```

If you just need a `Save(T entity)` or a `Insert(T entity)` and `Update(T entity)` depends a little bit on your architecture.

Comment: And I guess failures on any raise an exception?  Or should you return a `bool`?

Comment: Thanks Martin, I presume your Save method's logic would just be to lookup the current list of entities based on person.Id and then update each property?

Comment: @Daniel DiPaolo: Yep, if an exception occurs, you would throw a custom exception like `CouldNotSaveException()` or `ConcurrencyException()` which you handle then in the calling layer.

Comment: @Andy: Exactly! It depends a little bit on your own architecture if you'll just need a `Save(T entity)` which handles an insert and update or if you go with these two methods instead `Insert(T entity)` and `Update(T entity).

Comment: @Martin: potentially stupid question, but how would I implement that generic base repo? I'm getting issues trying to use the T as intellisense doesn't like it in method signatures. Or am I missing something incredibly obvious here?

Comment: @Martin: nevermind, had forgotten the <T> in my interface declaration. hehe!

Comment: @AndyC: I updated my answer a little bit. Something like `public interface IPersonRepository : IBaseRepository<Person> {}`.

Answer (score 1):

Your Delete method should look like this.

```
    void Delete(Person person);
```

If you need a more generic approach of the patterns, please take a look at this blog post: [Entity Framework Repository & Unit Of Work T4 Template](http://geekswithblogs.net/danemorgridge/archive/2010/06/28/entity-framework-repository-amp-unit-of-work-t4-template-on.aspx)